# Why is the instance attribute modified when << shoveling a value into the instance method call?

Tags: ruby

Why does the line, restaurant.menu << "pizza" , modify @menu attribute for our restaurant instance? The way I understand it is restaurant.menu is called and finishes evaluating to ["donuts", "cake"]. At this point the method call is done. So why is << pizza affecting the @menu attribute?

```
class Restaurant
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end

    def menu
        @menu = @menu || ["donuts", "cake"]
    end
end

restaurant = Restaurant.new("Mcdonalds")

p restaurant.menu             #["donuts", "cake"]

restaurant.menu << "pizza"    #???    

p restaurant.menu             #["donuts", "cake", "pizza"]>
```

Comment: Because the menu method is returning @menu.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's an implicit return and restaurant.menu evaluates to ["donuts", "cake"] which is then modified by << "pizza"

Comment: _"why is << pizza affecting the @menu attribute"_ – well, `<<` modifies the receiver and the receiver happens to be assigned to `@menu`. Remember that you modify objects, not variables.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for the comment. << modifies the receiver whereas if I did restaurant.menu + ["pizza"], this wouldn't modify the receiver and the output would just float in space, so to speak.. it would be evaluated/calculated but not modify the receiver..

Answer (score 2):

Although [@red_menace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10853463/red-menace) already answered what root cause is, but I will elaborate what that means.

First you need to understand Ruby objects mutability. [Here](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/01/ruby-mutability/) you can find some good article.

Basically in your example `menu` instance method of the class returns reference to instance variable `@menu` of the class' instance, which is mutable array (you can modify that through the reference).

If you really want to make it immutable, you can either [freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664050/ruby-freeze-method) the variable or clone it as it was suggested by [@Jad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835151/jad).

[Here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/best-way-to-protect-class-instance-variables/159784/3) you can find a great discussion on similar problem.

Here you can see an program trace that all the time you modify `menu` method's returned result you modified instance variable `@menu`.

```
require 'pp'

class Restaurant
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end

    def menu
        @menu = @menu || ["donuts", "cake"]
        puts "@menu object_id = #{@menu.object_id}"
        @menu
    end
end

restaurant = Restaurant.new("Mcdonalds")


p restaurant.menu             #["donuts", "cake"]

pp "object instance variables are #{restaurant.instance_variables}"


restaurant.menu << "pizza"    #???    

p restaurant.menu             #["donuts", "cake", "pizza"]>

p "restaurand.menu.object_id = #{restaurant.menu.object_id}"
```

Here is the program's output:

```
$ruby main.rb
@menu object_id = 47245049576960
["donuts", "cake"]
"object instance variables are [:@name, :@menu]"
@menu object_id = 47245049576960
@menu object_id = 47245049576960
["donuts", "cake", "pizza"]
@menu object_id = 47245049576960
"restaurand.menu.object_id = 47245049576960"
```

Comment: I didn't know it was mutable, thanks for the thorough explanation. Also playing around with .object_id really helps me get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: You're welcome! You might be interested also in Ruby metaprogramming topics, which will help you understand better Ruby internals.

Comment: @zzzcats note that the strings within the array are mutable, too (unless frozen). `restaurant.menu.last.replace('pasta')` would change the last item from `"pizza"` into `"pasta"`.

Comment: Noted, thanks. For some reason when I was learning this, I thought only setter methods could access the array elements and modify them, but that doesn't seem to be the case since as you've shown you can access the last element of the array and use string method replace and it'll "modify the receiver", good to have the new terminology to describe..

Answer (score 0):

As @red_menace suggests, it might be worthwhile trying something like:

```
class Restaurant
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @menu = ["donuts", "cake"]
    end

    def menu
        @menu.dup
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty interesting. It's a pretty useful way to keep my showing the same values of @menu. Also playing around with this and .object_id allowed me to see the dupes show a different memory location.